# Why is server configuration 'min server memory' configured at 0, but running at 16 (sometimes 8)?

Tags: sql-server, memory, configuration

We started to monitor sql server instance non-active server configurations and find something interesting.
Why is server configuration 'min server memory' configured at 0, but running at 16 (sometimes 8)?
The instances use the default value. 0 is the default and we don't change it, but apparently something changes it when SQL Server starts.
If this is the default behavior why isn't this value (16 or 8) configured as default instead of 0?

Does anyone have an (official/documented) explanation to this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is server configuration 'min server memory' configured at 0, but running at 16 (sometimes 8)? The instances use the default value. 0 is the default and we don't change it, but apparently something changes it when SQL Server starts

When you leave 'Min Server Memory' to default value of 0 this `does not` means that Lowest possible value `is 0`. The lowest possible value would be `16 MB`. This is **documented** in [This Blog.msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlosteam/archive/2012/07/12/memory-manager-configuration-changes-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

**For SQL Server 2008 R2**

```
Sp_configureOption   DefaultSetting     LowesPpossibleValue     HighestPossiblevalue

Min server memory          0                 16                Less Than Max server memory
```

**For SQL Server 2012**

```
Sp_configureOption   DefaultSetting     LowesPpossibleValue     HighestPossiblevalue

Min server memory          0                 16                Less Than Max server memory
```

Comment: I am sure that this will be the explanation. SQL Server has a default minimum configured implicitly. So I think the main question is, why there are instances (2005, 2008, 2008R2 | standard, enterprise | 32, 64 bit) where there is no implicit minimum memory configured?

Comment: Min server memory is mostly configured on environment where there are `multiple instances` on single machine and you don't want instance to give up memory beyond certain value. Mostly people don't know what actually min server memory does so does not bother about it. If you have single instance on a box you can leave min server memory to default.

Answer (score 2):

If the server is [involved in replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196734(v=sql.80).aspx) (remote Distributor or a combined Publisher/Distributor) then the `run_value` for `min server memory (MB)` will be set to `16 MB`.

If the server is not involved in replication, then the  `run_value` for `min server memory (MB)` will be set to `0 MB` by default.

**Note:** I confirmed the above statements by checking on the servers with and without replication.

I am not sure, where you see a value of `8 MB`.

Comment: I have checked lot of instances (~1800) as far as I can see replication has nothing to do with this option, but i can confirm the following:
in case of 32 bit instances the value is 8 MB; 
in case of 64 bit instances the value is 16 MB

But I still find instances where both value is 0...

Comment: @Robert its interesting, since I checked on 2008R2, 2012 and 2014 instances where replication was configured and where it was not configured.

Comment: So are you saying that all of your instances involved in replication (without an execption) the confiugred value is 0 and the running value is 16 MB, and all of your instances which are not involved in replication (also all = without an exeption) both value (configured and running) are 0? How many instances are we talking about here?

Comment: @Robert thats precisely true. I check on instances that are configured in T-Rep and without and I get what I mentioned in my answer. We are talking about more than 300+ instances running sql server 2008R2 and up.

Comment: Well that makes the things more interesting, since I have only 4 test server on my dev laptop, without any replication configured, and in case of SQL Server 2012 and 2014 the results is 0 - 16 not 0 -0.